# ASP.NET 5 dependency injection service error

Tags: asp.net-core

Playing with some code using the new ASP.NET 5 in VS 2015.  Had the code working and after adding some additional code to accommodate async for the Identity components I am getting:

> Could not resolve a service of type 'ClientExpress.Models.ClientExpressContextSeedData' for the parameter 'seeder' of method 'Configure' on type 'ClientExpress.Startup'.

Have a second project where I used the same Startup.cs flow including a context seeding class, async components and have zero problems with it.

Can't see anything different in the workflow other than names of classes.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        var connectionString = Configuration["Data:EAutoConnectionString"];

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ClientExpressContext>()
            .AddDbContext<ContactContext>(options =>
                 options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddScoped<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();

        services.AddTransient<ClientExpressContextSeedData>();

    }



    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ClientExpressContextSeedData seeder)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        //app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(config =>
            {
                config.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
                    );
            });

        await seeder.EnsureSeedDataAsync(); 


    }
```

ClientExpressContextSeedData.cs

```
public class ClientExpressContextSeedData
{
    private ClientExpressContext _context;
    private UserManager<ClientExpressUser> _userManager;

    public ClientExpressContextSeedData(ClientExpressContext context, UserManager<ClientExpressUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task EnsureSeedDataAsync()
    {


        if(await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("abc@testcompany.com") == null)
        {
            //Add Initial Users
            var newUser = new ClientExpressUser()
            {
                UserName = "newuser",
                Email = "abc@testcompany.com"
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "Pa$$w0rd");
        }



    }

}
```

If I remove the ClienExpressContextSeedData seeder from the Configure method, it then runs but of course no seeding happens.
The info I have found has this problem showing up a lot when repositories are used interchangeably with services accidentally but that isn't the case in this situation.
I am at a loss as to what is different or what about the injection is wrong.

Comment: Could you please add implementation of the ClientExpressUser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after looking into this more and playing around with the other dependencies, while the error message was point me at the seeding class, it turned out that the true issue was the ef 7 migrations.
I had built out the correct migrations but the latest migration added was not being properly applied to the database.  Two of the properties of a class that gets used by the seeder were set in the latest migration but was no getting applied (no errors thrown however).

Removed the migration, deleted the working database and then re-added the migration to make the database current.  New migration was not corrupt and the database built out properly.

Answer (score 0):

`ClientExpressContextSeedData` depends on `UserManager<ClientExpressUser>`

`UserManager<ClientExpressUser>` is not setup in your `ConfigureServices` method and therefor `ClientExpressContextSeedData` can't be resolved.

Add something like:

```
services.AddIdentity<ClientExpressUser, IdentityRole>()
```

Comment: SynerCoder, appreciate the suggestion.  The ClientExpressContextSeedData constructor is called during the injection and the UserManager is brought in that way.

Comment: Yes indeed. And the UserManager is not defined in your services. You need to call `services.AddIdentity<ClientExpressUser, IdentityRole>()` to setup the injection for it

Comment: SynerCoder, definitely appreciate the second look.  This particular issue was corrected by correcting the migration issue.

Comment: SynerCoder, apologies, two parter,
Later to implement the identity services and cookie services I did add the services.AddIdentity with some config lambdas.  You are correct that to make the service fully actionable requires the UserManager injection but was not the cause of this error.  Thanks again!